# How to solve problems of conditional probability using Bayes theorem?

Tags: probability-theory

I don't understand how to solve problems of conditional probability.Here's a problem which I fail to understand."Consider all families with two children and assume that each child is equally likely to be a boy or a girl.If such a family is chosen at random and found to have a boy,then what is the probability that it has another boy."Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [Try this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131622/a-very-easy-probability-problem-but-opinions-diverge-greatly-need-some-help) for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event that the family have a boy and $B$ be the event that the family has another boy.

Then $P(B|A)=P(AB)/P(A)=(1/4)/(3/4)=(1/3)$

Comment: How P(A)=3/4?It should be 2/3.Because the combination (boy,girl) and (girl,boy) is symmetric.Is it not right?

Comment: @ArnabChattopadhyay Read my comment.

Comment: @ArnabChattopadhyay  Since the sample space is $S=\{BB,BG,GB,GG\}$, there are $3$ of them in event $A$

Answer (score 1):

When we say that the probability of an event $A$ is conditioned on an event $B$, we can think of this intuitively as, what's the chance that $A$ happens knowing $B$ is something that already happened?

You might hopefully be familiar with the expression with $P(A|B)$ being the probability of $A$ given $B$:

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

As you can see, we're considering the event of $A$ and $B$ happening, divided by $P(B)$. You can think of this as $P(B)$ becoming our 'sample space' as it is the event of interest regarding $A$'s probability, what are the odds that $A$ occurs if $B$ occurs? Why this sample space intuition comes around is simply that:

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{|A \cap B|}{|S|}}{\frac{|B|}{|S|}}=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|S|}\times \frac{|S|}{|B|}=\frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|}$, where $S$ is our sample space.

Let's model the problem, as it is good to do so. What is our sample space?

$S=${$BB,BG,GB,GG$}, where $G$ denotes a girl, and $B$ denotes a boy. You don't necessarily have to write out the sample space but this is to get a better understanding of what's happening. Be aware that the gender of each child is independent of one another, so you will see as to why we ought to consider $BG$ and $GB$ to be in our sample space.

Then let $B_1$ be the event that ***one of children of the family is a boy***. This is important. And let $B_0$ denote the event that the ***other*** child is a boy.

We seek $P(B_0|B_1)$ = $P(B_0 \cap B_1)/P(B_1)$. This is the probability that the other child is a boy in the family given that one of them is a boy.

Can you piece together the end result?