# You've been told that a family has two children and one of these is a daughter.

Tags: probability

You know that family has two children and at least one of these is a daughter. Now suppose that you ring the doorbell and a daughter opens the door. Assuming that each of the two children answer the doorbell with equal probability what is the probability you now assign to the family having two daughters?

A: family has two daughters;  B : family has one daughter; C : daughter opens the door

$P(C/A) = 1$

$P(C/B) = \frac 1 2$

$P(A/C) = \frac 1 {1+ \frac 1 2} = \frac 2 3 $

Is this correct ?

Comment: Your working is a little unclear, and I'm not sure how you got $1/1+1/2=2/3$, but consider that P(2 daughters) = P(2 daughters | known child answers) $\cdot$ P(known child answers) + P(2 daughters | unknown child answers) $\cdot$ P(unknown child answers) $= 1/2\cdot 1/2+1\cdot 1/2=3/4$.

Comment: What you wrote is hard to follow.  First of all, $\frac 11+\frac 12$ is not $\frac 23$.  Secondly, you never seem to consider the a priori probabilities of the events $A,B$.  Those surely matter...seeing the daughter at the door allows you to revise your estimate, but you need to start somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability that both 2 already born children are girls given that one of them is a girl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461102/probability-that-both-2-already-born-children-are-girls-given-that-one-of-them-i)

Comment: Of course , in those exercises it is assumed that the probability for each child to be a girl is 1/2 , whether this is a realistic assumption or not. With this assumption, this is a simple exercise about Bayes' theorem.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't think the question you linked to is an equivalent question to this one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to apply [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) which tells us that

$\displaystyle P(A|C) = \frac {P(C|A)P(A)}{P(C)}$

where event A is "family has two daughters given that the family has two children and at least one daughter" and event C is "a daughter answers the door given that the family has two children and at least one daughter".

You know that $P(C|A)=1$ and $P(A) = \frac 1 3$. If $\lnot A$ (which I think you are calling B) then the family has one son and one daughter, so $P(C|\lnot A) = \frac 1 2$ (this is where we use the information that one of the children will answer the door, and each child is equally likely to answer the door). So we can find $P(C)$ as follows

$\displaystyle P(C) = P(C|A)P(A) + P(C|\lnot A)P(\lnot A) = \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3 = \frac 2 3$

which gives us

$\displaystyle P(A|C) = \frac 1 3 \times \frac 3 2 = \frac 1 2$

Another way to see this is as follows. There are two scenarios in which a daughter answers the door:

1. The family has two daughters and one of them answers the door - probability $\frac 1 3$.
2. The family has one son and one daughter and the daughter answers the door - probability $\frac 2 3 \times \frac 1 2 = \frac 1 3$.

Since these two scenarios are equally likely, the probability that we have scenario 1 is $\frac 1 2$.