# A family having 4 children has 3 girl children. What is the probability that their 4th child is a son?

Tags: probability

This is similar to the [two child problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/in-a-family-with-two-children-what-are-the-chances-if-one-of-the-children-is-a).

So there are five cases, the gender of the children written according to their age,

1. GGGG
2. GGGB
3. GGBG
4. GBGG
5. BGGG

So the probability should be $\frac{4}{5}$. But the given answer is $\frac{3}{4}$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where does the "given answer" come from?

Comment: My friend gave it. He said it is from a book. I will let know about it when I come to know the name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem statement says that a family has 4 kids, and that 3 of them are girls. Because they don't say *"at least"* 3 of them are girls, we understand they what they actually mean is **"exactly"** 3 of them are girls and the remaining kid is a boy. What is the probability that the $4$th child is a boy?

By $4$th child they mean the youngest. So how are the genders distributed among ages? We can have either of the $4$:

- GGGB;
- GGBG;
- GBGG;
- BGGG;

where the leftmost is the older sibling and the rightmost is the younger one. Thus, out of those $4$ possible arrangements, only in one the youngest kid is a boy and thus the answer should be $\frac14$. $\frac34$ is the answer to "what is the probability that the 4th kid is a girl" or "what is the probability that the boy is not the 4th kid" or anything along those lines.

Comment: Nice way to get to $\frac{1}{4}$!  Can we think of a feasible scenario that gets us to $\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it would be better phrased that way, yes, if we assume your friend gave you the wrong answer by mistake, 1 minus the right answer actually, thus making the right answer $\frac14$. For the answer to be $\frac34$ it is more likely that your friend forgot a word when giving you the problem statement.

Comment: @Bram28 I find it more likely that his friend made a mistake when giving him the problem statement than there being a situation where the right answer actually is $\frac34$ - given the information we have as of now

Comment: I agree.  Which shows another important aspect of these kinds of probability questions: as stated in English, questions about probabilitycan often be interpreted in many different ways.

Answer (score 2):

In a real life situation, it depends on *how* you know that the family has 3 girls. Here are two different scenarios:

A. You run into the mother with 3 of her children with her that are all girls, and she tells you that she has a 4th child. Now the chance of the 4th child being a boy is $\frac{1}{2}$

B. You are in a room with a bunch of parents, and someone asks: 'who is a parent of exactly 4 children, at least 3 of which are girls?', and the mother of this family raises her hand. Now the probability of her 4th child being a boy is $\frac{4}{5}$, following exactly your explanation.

There may be other scenarios yet, leading to different answers yet, and some might even lead to a probability of $\frac{3}{4}$, but I think scenarios isomorph to either one of these two cases are most likely to happen in real life. So I don't like the answer of the book either.

Comment: I hate dubious probability questions :P

Comment: @RSerrao I kind of like them! :) It really urges us to think real clear about the assumptions we are making when we are doing math, and whether they apply to a real life situation.