# Why is this coin-flip not memoryless and independent of past coin-flips for a fair coin, so we have to use bayes theorem and conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

> A man flips a fair coin with sides heads and tails five times. Given that the man receives heads on at least two of the coin flips, what is the probability that he receives tails exactly twice after the five flips of the coin?

A.$\frac{1}{4}$
B.$\frac{5}{16}$
C.$\frac{5}{13}$
D.$\frac{3}{8}$
E.$\frac{8}{13}$

This process is memoryless and we have a $p=\dfrac{1}{2}$

What happened on two flips after five flips is the same as what happens on any two flips.

I think the answer is A but answer key says C.

Comment: (Not answering the question) I wonder, if you believe that memoryless is applicable, why wouldn't you consider the required probability the same as receiving tails exactly twice after three flips of the coin, i.e. D. $3/8$?

Comment: I think it's poor phrasing, and the question means to ask about the probability exactly two of the same five flips are tails. Possibly using "after" in the sense of "After the five flips are performed, the total he received"

Comment: This may be similar to the [Boy or Girl paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox), but in this case "Mr. Smith has five children. At least two of them are boys. What is the probability that exactly two children are girls?"

Comment: Previous [coins problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889845) and [children problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15055).

Comment: As I read it, this is a trick question and the answer is 1/4. The trick is to force you to notice that when you have independent events, what has been seen so far does not matter for the future.

Comment: Another interpretation is let $X$ the number of heads. You want $P(X = 2 \mid X \geq 2).$ In this case you get $P(X=2)/(P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5))=\ldots=\dfrac{5}{13}.$

Comment: @WilliamM. He said that the answer key gives 5/13 in the question, so the answer is not 1/4.

Comment: @SuzuHirose many times probability and or statistic questions are paradoxes soleley because of the wording rather than the mathematics (the mathematics does not reaches contradictions). The wording can be interpreted in several different ways. _REGARDLESS_ of what the answer was, my first reading was what I said, and I've even written books in the subject. (I wouldn't know where this material came from but a lot of basic material is written by non-mathematicians in a more "interpret me" fashion than in a "here is a correctly unambiguous statement" one.)

Comment: @SuzuHirose In fact, statisticians do no write mathematics (and statistics is not mathematics!) Rather, they write statements of real problems and they want to somehow translate them into mathematics, this obviously creates many different, plausible and sensible, approaches. This is easily reflected in the fact that there are many dozen of overlapping algorithms for the same task or that other problems (e.g. Behrens-Fisher probem) have largely been unanswered and the existing solutions are not widely accepted (because the different interpretations require different approaches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Given that* here should be interpreted as *In the condition that*, which is a case of [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), quoting Wikipedia:

> In probability theory, conditional probability is a measure of the probability of an event occurring, given that another event (by assumption, presumption, assertion or evidence) has already occurred.

We define

- $A$ to be the event that the man receives exactly two tails.
- $B$ to be the event that he gets more than one head.

So the probability of getting at least two heads on 5 flips is

$$
P(B)=1 - \left(\frac 12 \right)^5-\binom{5}{1}\left(\frac 12 \right)^5 = \frac{13}{16}
$$

While getting exactly two tails **as well as getting at least two heads** is

$$
P(A\cap B) = \binom{5}{2}\left(\frac 12 \right)^5 = \frac{5}{16}
$$

Note: This value is the same as $P(A)$ because **having exactly two tails *implies* that he's got at least two heads (three, actually)**.

Using the formula for conditional probability, that is,

$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

We get,

$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{\frac{5}{16}}{\frac{13}{16}} = \frac 5{13}
$$

Which is what we wanted.

If $P(A|B) = P(A)$, then $A$ and $B$ must be independent. That is, knowledge about either event does not alter the likelihood of each other. Explained in English: As you *already know that* there are at least $2$ tails, the probability of it *still* having $2$ heads is changed relevant to not knowing anything.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer as to what the ambiguous question means.

Comment: Why $1 - \left(\frac 12 \right)^5$? @LilyWhite

Comment: @BoredStar We are calculating the complementary because there are only two scenarios: no heads and 1 head, $\left(\frac 12\right)^5$ means heads on _none_ of the tosses, which (fairly) should be written as $\left(1 - \frac 12\right)^5$ to be clearer.

Comment: What is $P(A \cap B)$?@ LilyWhite

Comment: @BoredStar Wikipedia is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Theory

Comment: Where is $P(A \cap B)$ in your answer? $P(A|B) \neq \dfrac{5}{16}/\dfrac{13}{16}$

Comment: @BoredStar My fault, it should be $P(A\cap B)$ there. The trick is that having exactly two tails implies that he's got three ($\ge 2$!) heads.

Answer (score 2):

> > A man flips a fair coin with sides heads and tails *five times*. Given that the man receives heads on *at least two* of the coin flips, what is the probability that he receives tails *exactly twice* after **the** five flips of the coin?

This is poorly phrased.   My reading is that there are no further flips; the question is in regard to the result of these five flips.

To rephrase: "After the five flips: what is the probability that exactly two tails we obtained *given that* at least two heads were obtained."

> Why is this coin-flip not memoryless and independent of past coin-flips for a fair coin, so we have to use bayes theorem and conditional probability?

They are the same five flips, not independent trials.

---

So we seek: "The probability for obtaining exactly two tails, given that *at most* three tails were among the five."

And thus Bayes' Rule is the appropriate to find the answer of $\underline{\phantom{5/13}}$.