# A family has two children. What is the probability that both the children are boys given that at least one of them is a boy?

Tags: probability, terminology

This is a question from my mathematics textbook. I am studying conditional probability and know how to solve this problem. Where I get confused is that my book treats the cases:(boy, girl) & (girl, boy) differently, i.e., as if they are not the same. Why does the order matter here? By the way, I know that the answer is $\frac13$ if you do it this way. And according to my understanding it should be $\frac12$ as I don't see why the possibilities of the family having (boy, girl) & (girl, boy) are different, although they mean the same thing.

Comment: This is something that has already featured on MSO. (Many times.) [In a family with two children, what are the chances, if one of the children is a girl, that both children are girls?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/in-a-family-with-two-children-what-are-the-chances-if-one-of-the-children-is-a) Please go through this post and any linked posts and maybe you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Shortly, you don't need to consider the cases (boy, girl) and (girl, boy) separate, you can consider them one case, but the fact is that _that_ case is then twice as likely as any of the cases (boy, boy) or (girl, girl).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox